# While attempting to create controlleralbumcontroller(alias: Controller\AlbumController) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type

Tags: php, module, controller, zend-framework2, factory

I have created AlbumControllerFactory.php in folder **\module\Album\src\Album\Factory** as follows: But it is showing error a mentioned above

```
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;

class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
/**
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface $container
 * @param string $requestedName
 * @param null|array $options
 * @return AlbumController
 */
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : AlbumController::class;
    $albumTable = $container->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable'); // get service from service manager
    $controller = new $class($albumTable);

    return $controller;

}
/**
 * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
 * @return AlbumController
 */
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
{
    return $this($container, AlbumController::class);
}
}
```

And in my controller i have following code to get my factory:

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Album\Model\Album;  
use Album\Form\AlbumForm;  

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{

protected $_albumTable;

 public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable)
 {
     $this->_albumTable = $albumTable;
 }


 public function indexAction()
 {
     return new ViewModel(array(
         'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
     ));
 }
```

}

And in my module.config.php i have set the controller as like follows:

```
return array(
 'controllers' => array(
'factories' => array(
    Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
),
```

),

So How i can fix this issue in-order to make my module work fine as it was working fine before creating the factory but it was showing a deprecated message. Please have a look at let me know what wrong i have done and how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have `use Album\Controller` and `use Album\Factory` at the top in `module.config.php` file?

Comment: Still the same error: @SzymonM

Comment: What is a namespace in `AlbumControllerFactory` class?

Comment: namespace Album\Factory; this one

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example of how to use factories in Zend 2/3. I guess you are missing namespace in `module.config.php` file, but please compare your namespaces and directories with these.

You should have following directory structure:

```
module
  - Album
    - config
        module.config.php
    - src
      - Controller
          AlbumController.php
      - Factory
        - Controller
            AlbumControllerFactory.php
    - Module.php
```

**Factory**

```
namespace Album\Factory\Controller

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;

class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
/**
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface $container
 * @param string $requestedName
 * @param null|array $options
 * @return AlbumController
 */
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : AlbumController::class;
    $albumTable = $container->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable'); // get service from service manager
    $controller = new $class($albumTable);

    return $controller;

}
/**
 * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
 *
 * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
 * @return AlbumController
 */
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
{
    return $this($container, AlbumController::class);
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Album\Model\Album;  
use Album\Form\AlbumForm;  

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{

protected $_albumTable;

 public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable)
 {
     $this->_albumTable = $albumTable;
 }


 public function indexAction()
 {
     return new ViewModel(array(
         'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
     ));
 }

}
```

**module.config.php**

```
namespace Album;

use Album\Controller;
use Album\Factory;

return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'factories' => array(
        Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
     ),
),
```

I like to have segregated factories, but you can keep all your factories in main `Factory` directory, but be sure to set correct namespaces for them and in `module.config.php` file

Comment: more complete answer than mine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about Namespace :

You said :

> I have created AlbumControllerFactory.php in folder
>   \module\Album\src\Album\Factory

BUT you call

```
Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
```

`Factory\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory` is not a correct Full Qualified Class Name (FQCN)

You should have this in your config file

Suppose your namespace **declared in the config file** is Album :

```
Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\AlbumControllerFactory::class
```

Comment: As i said you have a namespace problem, the full example given by @SzymonM should be solve your problem.